# Silex and Twig: global.request.baseUrl is empty

Tags: php, twig, silex, base-url

My URL is looking like this:

> www.MyWebsite.nl/Escape/public/user

So in my twig template, I should be able to use the following line for an image:

```
<img src='{{ global.request.baseUrl }}/img/EscapeRoom.png' class="slide">
```

But for some reason that does not work... the baseUrl should contain:

> /Escape/public

But it is empty, can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

### EDIT

When I go to the following page:

> www.MyWebsite.nl/Escape/public/user/login

Css, images etc. don't work anymore, since the path isn't correct anymore (two words after 'public'). Do you know how that problem can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, the way that you are structuring the URL is fundamentally wrong. You should use absolute URLs that *URL Generator* in Silex produces that is bound to the respective route.

**Register URL Generator:**

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
```

**Name your routes:**

```
$app->get('/', function () {
return 'welcome to the homepage';
})->bind('homepage');
```

In your template code, to get the `URL of the homepage`, use

```
{{ app.url_generator.generate('homepage') }}
```

Also, you need to use .htaccess based URL rewrite rules on your public directory to beautify URLs. That will help you to map your static assets simply by writing the path like below.

```
<img src='img/EscapeRoom.png' class="slide">
```

This requires that you use .htaccess file to rewrite your site URL and point the public directory as your site root in your hosting provider.

[Silex - URL Generator](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.3/providers/url_generator.html)

Comment: That already helped me out a lot! Thanks for that, but I've got one more question. Please check my edit

Comment: Glad it helped. You first need to fix the site root to point to public. Change it so that your URL becomes - "www.MyWebsite.nl/user/login". Everything else will follow.

Comment: It has to be this way, since I'm also using another project on this domain. Someone else refered to  AssetServiceProvider, do you think this might be helpfull? I've tried it, but I could not really get it working

Comment: Yes, AssetServiceProvider is the best way to go in that case. Make sure you follow that. Reading this document will help https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/asset.html

Comment: I've got it working now! Thank you very much for your help! It is very much appreciated!!!!